# Making a circle navigator in html

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a circle navigator ?
example a circle divided into 4 and each division has different links on it?

and also if it is possible can i put animations on them or color change when a mouse hover? tnx...

Comment: What hv you tried? Show your code...

Comment: i havemnt tried anyhting yet, i just tried searching google and i cant seem to find a tut for it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `border-radius`

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle-container">
<div class="quarter top-left"><a href="#">link 1</a></div>
<div class="quarter top-right"><a href="#">link 2</a></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-left"><a href="#">link 3</a></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-right"><a href="#">link 4</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle-container{width:100px;height:100px}
.quarter{width:50px;height:50px}
.top-left{border-top-left-radius:50px;background:#e3f9d1;float:left}
.top-right{border-top-right-radius:50px;background:#c0f7f7;float:right}
.bottom-left{border-bottom-left-radius:50px;background:#fc92f5;float:left}
.bottom-right{border-bottom-right-radius:50px;background:#333;float:right}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
    width:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9zdHw/1/)**

Comment: You can use `overflow: hidden` and `border-radius: 50%` on the containing element. http://jsfiddle.net/fa5Mf/

Comment: thanks, ill try it later, ill jsut give you an upvote for replying :D te check vote for later..

Comment: what if the circle is divided into more links?

Comment: Its working.. Thanks!!! Now im gonna experiment inserting animations on it. if ever its possible because im planning to make a cool unique navigator.

Comment: @FrankieRoySanquiNiverba Cool. All the best. post the final link when you are done with the navigation menu

Comment: @Sowmya hope i manage to do what im really planning. Not just all expectation.LOL